# is special attribute vs v-if / v-show

Tags: vue.js

[is special attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) is:

```
<!-- Component changes when currentTabComponent changes -->
<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```

[conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) is:

```
<div v-if="type === 'A'">
  A
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'B'">
  B
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'C'">
  C
</div>
<div v-else>
  Not A/B/C
</div>
```

I know the different between using `v-if` and `v-show`, but I don't know the difference between using a list of `v-if`s for different cases vs using the `is` special attribute. When should I use them?

Does `is` work like `v-if` or `v-show`? I mean, does it render all the components anyways? Is `is` like a syntactic sugar for a list of subsequent `v-if`s?

Comment: an example could be: you have a login and an register component. In this case its good to use `:is`. When somebody wants to register you just set it to the register component `:is="register"` otherwise you set it to `:is="login"`. An usecase for `v-if` could be for a sidebar on mobile. If you press the menu button you set that specific component to true with `v-if` and it renders, if you close the sidebar then you just press X somehwere. You can also wrap it in `<transition>` to make nice fading / sliding transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` would be useful if the list of `v-if`s would all render a component if true.

Like so:

```
<template v-if="component == "firstComponent">
    <first-component></first-component>
<template v-else-if="component == "secondComponent">
    <second-component></second-component>
</template>
<template v-else-if="component == "thirdComponent">
    <third-component></third-component>
</template>
```

This can then be reduced to:

```
<component :is="component"></component>
```

### Concerning your second question

Wether `component :is` works like `v-if` or `v-show` depends on wether you wrap it in `<keep-alive>` or not. Read the documentation on this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components). Note though, that using `<component>` a component only gets created until it is necessary the first time, wether you use `<keep-alive>` or not.

So:

- `v-if` (re)creates the component everytime the condition is met.
- `<component :is="...">` creates the component everytime the condition is met (like `v-if`).
- `<keep-alive><component :is="..."></keep-alive>` creates the
  component at most 1 time (but possibly 0).
- A component with only `v-show` on it is created exactly once.

Comment: Does is work like v-if or v-show? I mean, does it render all the components anyways?